# pass argument to DAG, task apache airflow

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow

I'm exploring `apache airflow 1.8`. I'm curious that either is there any way to pass arguments to `DAGs` or `tasks` while `backfilling`?

Here is something like that I'm searching for,

```
airflow backfill My_DAG -s some_date -e end_date argument_for_t1 argument_for_t2
```

or it could be `array` of args.

is there any way to pass arguments? I've searched a lot, but wasn't able to find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the solution that I can set the variables using `airflow variables -s my_var="some value"`

Now I can access `my_var` anywhere across the application.

for more options check [cli](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/cli.html)

Comment: this is acceptable if you're having a single run at a time. For various concurrent runs with different variables this won't work, since the variables are global.

Answer (score 2):

Backfill is to re-run a failed/missed/mis configured DAG and hence there is no provision to give command line arguments.

However, you can go to DagBag folder and give params to the dag object (Change/fix existing dag)  and then back fill the DAG